# TypeError: navigator.currentLang is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 to develop a mobile application. The following are the information of my ionic installation:

- Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v6.9.2
- Xcode version: Not installed

I have an `extension.ts` file that contains various extensions of predefined types of TypeScript/JavaScript, including the following class:

```
export {};

declare global {
    interface Navigator {
        currentLang() : string;
    }
}

Navigator.prototype.currentLang = function() {
    var userLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0];
    userLang = /(en|it)/gi.test(userLang) ? userLang : 'en';
    return userLang;
};
```

When I run the command `ionic serve` the google developer console shows the following error:

`TypeError: navigator.currentLang is not a function`

What could be the problem?
Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Can you show the part of your code that uses this function? How are you importing `extension.ts`?

Comment: I'm using `navigator.currentLang` in `app.componet.ts` inside the `platform.ready().then(...)` callback. I'm importing the extensions at the top of `app.componet.ts` using the line `import { } from '../extensions'`;

Answer (score 0):

The compiled output of this code:

```
import { } from '../extensions';
console.log(navigator.currentLang());
```

Assuming the default module option is:

```
console.log(navigator.currentLang());
```

There's no import in the js file so when you try to run it in the browser it won't load `../extensions.js` and therefor `navigator.currentLang` is undefined.
This is because you haven't actually imported anything from the module.

The syntax for that is:

```
import '../extensions';
console.log(navigator.currentLang());
```

Which compiles to:

```
require("../extensions");
console.log(navigator.currentLang());
```